# Modal doesn't appear on the mobile version

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem is that the modal window fails to open on mobile devices and Safari browsers. I was trying to remove 'position' but this doesn't work, maybe here is another problem that i don't understand. hese properties were previously responsible for ensuring the modal's visibility within the viewport. Without them, the modal lacks the necessary positioning cues to display correctly, particularly on mobile devices and in Safari browsers. To resolve this, an alternative method must be devised to display the modal window effectively without relying on position, possibly by adjusting other CSS properties such as display and visibility to ensure proper visibility across different devices and browsers. Can someone help me please with this problem?

```
<div class="modal__overlay">
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal__content">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <form>
          <div>
            <label for="name">{{main-text.form-name}}</label>
            <input required type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="{{main-text.name-placeholder}}" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="phone">{{main-text.form-phone}}</label>
            <input
              type="phone"
              id="phone"
              name="phone"
              placeholder="{{main-text.phone-placeholder}}"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="textarea">{{main-text.form-questions}}</label>
            <textarea
              id="textarea"
              rows="2"
              name="textarea"
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <button class="submit-btn">{{main-text.form-send}}</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="thank-you">  <svg
        style="width: 120px"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        version="1.1"
        id="Capa_1"
        viewBox="0 0 434.71 434.71"
        xml:space="preserve"
        fill="#000000"
      >
        <g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g>
        <g
          id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier"
          stroke-linecap="round"
          stroke-linejoin="round"
        ></g>
        <g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier">
          <g>
            <g>
              <line
                style="
                  fill: none;
                  stroke: #000000;
                  stroke-width: 15;
                  stroke-linecap: round;
                  stroke-linejoin: round;
                  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                "
                x1="261.207"
                y1="290.898"
                x2="328.358"
                y2="340.123"
              ></line>
            </g>
            <polygon
              style="fill: #ffefca"
              points="79.73,234.613 354.87,234.613 354.87,126.5 354.87,19.24 79.73,19.24 "
            ></polygon>
            <g>
              <path
                style="fill: #ffdfa1"
                d="M303.715,71.294H128.797c-4.143,0-7.5-3.357-7.5-7.5s3.357-7.5,7.5-7.5h174.918 c4.143,0,7.5,3.357,7.5,7.5S307.858,71.294,303.715,71.294z"
              ></path>
            </g>
            <g>
              <path
                style="fill: #ffdfa1"
                d="M303.715,117.499H128.797c-4.143,0-7.5-3.357-7.5-7.5s3.357-7.5,7.5-7.5h174.918 c4.143,0,7.5,3.357,7.5,7.5S307.858,117.499,303.715,117.499z"
              ></path>
            </g>
            <g>
              <rect
                x="0.152"
                y="173.787"
                style="fill: #d3e8f1"
                width="434.558"
                height="241.683"
              ></rect>
              <path
                style="fill: #bed8e4"
                d="M261.918,288.805L434.71,415.47H0.152c0-2.912,171.502-120.842,171.502-120.842l30.126-18.834 L261.918,288.805z"
              ></path>
            </g>
            <polyline
              style="fill: #bed8e4"
              points="413.836,173.787 434.71,173.787 434.71,415.47 414.906,415.47 "
            ></polyline>
            <polygon
              style="fill: #b1c6d3"
              points="216.229,335.56 216.597,335.791 277.416,299.624 246.2,277.139 219.943,275.74 "
            ></polygon>
            <polygon
              style="fill: #bed8e4"
              points="277.416,299.624 427.837,199.23 427.837,176.965 249.372,275.618 256.908,285.209 "
            ></polygon>
            <path
              style="fill: #b1c6d3"
              d="M187.483,281.632c17.953,16.619,30.718,28.741,30.718,29.61c0,4.111-1.604,24.549-1.604,24.549 l-54.656-34.547"
            ></path>
            <path
              style="fill: #bed8e4"
              d="M161.94,301.245L0,198.888v-25.101l73.304,3.863c0,0,71.647,64.61,114.178,103.982"
            ></path>
            <polygon
              style="fill: #ebf9fe"
              points="0.152,173.787 217.431,315.011 434.572,173.888 "
            ></polygon>
          </g>
        </g>
        <br />
        <p class="title">{{main-text.thank-you-modal}} <br /></p>
       <p class="subtitle">{{main-text.be-in-touch}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal__close">
        <svg
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          version="1.1"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          fill="#000000"
        >
          <g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g>
          <g
            id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          ></g>
          <g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier">
            <title>Close</title>
            <g
              id="Page-1"
              stroke="none"
              stroke-width="1"
              fill="none"
              fill-rule="evenodd"
            >
              <g id="Close">
                <rect
                  id="Rectangle"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                  x="0"
                  y="0"
                  width="24"
                  height="24"
                ></rect>
                <line
                  x1="16.9999"
                  y1="7"
                  x2="7.00001"
                  y2="16.9999"
                  id="Path"
                  stroke="#0C0310"
                  stroke-width="2"
                  stroke-linecap="round"
                ></line>
                <line
                  x1="7.00006"
                  y1="7"
                  x2="17"
                  y2="16.9999"
                  id="Path"
                  stroke="#0C0310"
                  stroke-width="2"
                  stroke-linecap="round"
                ></line>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.modal__overlay {
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s opacity ease;
}
.modal {
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  padding: 36px 24px;
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  &__overlay {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 100;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0s;
    &.active {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  &__close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    svg {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
    }
  }
  .title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black
  }
  textarea {
      resize: vertical;
  }
.submit-btn {
    background:  $backgroundPrimary;
    color: white
}
  &__content {
    display: block;
    &.hidden {
      display: none;
    }
    div {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
      &:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 24px;
      }
    }
    label {
      font-size: 16px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 4px;
    }
  }
  &__content input,
  textarea {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
  }
  .submit-btn {
    margin-top: 18px;
    background: $backgroundPrimary;
    padding: 14px 12px;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    transition: 0s;
    &.success {
      filter: brightness(1.1);
      transition: .3s all;
    }
  }
  .thank-you {
    height: 0;
    display: none;
    &.active {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 200px;
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      transition: .3s all;
      .title {
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
      .subtitle {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        line-height: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

js:

```
const modalOverlay = document.querySelector(".modal__overlay");
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const modalCloseBtn = document.querySelector(".modal__close");
const buttonTriggerOpenModal = document.querySelectorAll(".trigger-modal");

const nameField = document.getElementById('name');
const phoneField = document.getElementById('phone');
const questionsField = document.getElementById('textarea');

const modalContent = document.querySelector('.modal__content');
const thankYou = document.querySelector('.thank-you');

function closeModal() {
  modalOverlay.classList.remove("active");
  document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
  nameField.value = '';
  phoneField.value = '';
  questionsField.value = '';
}

function openModal() {
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  modalOverlay.classList.add("active");
  nameField.value = '';
  phoneField.value = '';
  questionsField.value = '';

  thankYou.style.display = 'none'

  modalContent.classList.remove('hidden')
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  buttonTriggerOpenModal.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => openModal());
  });
  modalOverlay.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (!e.target.closest(".modal")) {
      closeModal();
    }
  });
  modalCloseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => closeModal());
  const form = document.querySelector(".modal form");
  form.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formdata = new FormData(document.querySelector(".modal form"));
    const name = formdata.get("name");
    const phone = formdata.get("phone");
    const questions = formdata.get("textarea");

    let headers = {
      "Content-type": "",
      Authorization: ``,
    };

    let params = {
      user_id: "",
      service_id: "",
      template_id: "",
      template_params: {
        name: name,
        phone: phone,
        questions: questions,
      },
    };

    try {
      await fetch("", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(params),
      });

      thankYou.classList.add('active')

      thankYou.style.display = 'flex';

      modalContent.classList.add('hidden')

      setTimeout(() => {
        closeModal();
      }, 3000)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  });
});
```